# One access modifier for multiple variables in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, access-modifiers

This might sound really stupid, but I wondered if it is possible to declare multiple variables using one access modifier. This is possible in C++:

```
public:
    int x;
    int y;
```

is anything like this possible in C#?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There isn't a comparable C# syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can only modify individual variables.

```
public int x;
public int y;
```